# How I make the search only work when I hit enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have search box and I'm using this code to show the results from mysql databse with almost 9,000,000 raw
But becuse I have big database I want it to only show the results when someone type a word and then hit enter, and no data rendering when someone open the page.
By defults it's live search box right now

This is my code: but it doesnt work?

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    if(search != '')
    if (event.key === "Enter")
    {
        load_data(search);
    }
    else
    {
        load_data();            
    }

});
```

Comment: this is because your listener is set to keyup. Place it to button div with a submit listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `load_data` call in your `else` and `return` out of the function:

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '') {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It's because in your `$(document).ready()`, you're calling `load_data()`. Remove this.

Comment: wow that's so awsome, I spent the whole day on that :D thanks